# How to change date from database into array with php

Tags: php

I don't know, how to change date from database into array.

Can someone help me to fix it? Please find below my code :

```
require ('sss_connection.php');
$koneksi = mysql_connect($server,$user,$pass);
$db=mysql_select_db($db);

$sql7="select tanggallibur from harilibur";
$ambil_data7=mysql_query($sql7);
while($data= mysql_fetch_array($ambil_data7))
        {
            $tanggal_libur = $data['tanggallibur'];

        }   


    $tglLibur = array($tanggal_libur);
```

`$data['tanggallibur']` is date in database

I expected for is to reduce the working day by day off, example = 2015-01-01 until 2015-01-08 weekdays obtained is 5 days, this has included cutting the saturday and Sunday. i know how to cut working day for saturday and sunday, but i dont know how to cut working day with offday (holiday).

Comment: What is the output of current code and what is your expected output?

Comment: I expected for is to reduce the working day by day off, example = 2015-01-01 until 2015-01-08 weekdays obtained is 5 days, this has included cutting the saturday and Sunday. i know how to cut working day for saturday and sunday, but i dont know how to cut working day with offday (holiday).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to assign database column to a separate array ? then 
you want to change

```
$tanggal_libur = $data['tanggallibur'];
```

to

```
$tanggal_libur[] = $data['tanggallibur'];
```

and the complete code would be

```
require ('sss_connection.php');
$koneksi = mysql_connect($server,$user,$pass);
$db=mysql_select_db($db);

$sql7="select tanggallibur from harilibur";
$ambil_data7=mysql_query($sql7);
while($data= mysql_fetch_array($ambil_data7))
{
    $tanggal_libur[] = $data['tanggallibur'];    
}   

print_r($tanggal_libur);
```

Comment: I expected for is to reduce the working day by day off, example = 2015-01-01 until 2015-01-08 weekdays obtained is 5 days, this has included cutting the saturday and Sunday. i know how to cut working day for saturday and sunday, but i dont know how to cut working day with offday (holiday).